# how to use javaScript - Yii2 for menu

Tags: javascript, php, yii2-advanced-app

i created menu for my yii 1 application by using following code:

```
<nav class="navigation">
                <ul class="navigationList" id="myTopnav">
                    <li class="expanded navigationList-item">
                    <a href="#section803" class="navigationList-link">Наши контакты</a>
                </li>
                    <li class="first expanded navigationList-item">
                        <a href="#section804" class="navigationList-link">О компании</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="expanded navigationList-item">
                        <a href="#section805" class="navigationList-link">О членство ТПП</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="expanded navigationList-item">
                    <a href="#section806" class="navigationList-link">моe цели</a></li>
                    <li class="last leaf navigationList-item--border navigationList-item">
                        <a href="https://www.chamber.com/contact" class="navigationList-link">Личины кабинет</a>
                    </li>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myMenu()" class="click">&#9776;</a>
                        <ul class="nav" id="nav_bar">
                            <li><a href="#section803">Наши контакты</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section804">О компании</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section805">О членство ТПП</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section806">моe цели</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Личины кабинет</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>

            </nav>
            <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>../../Index/script_nav.js"></script>
```

it worked properly(picture).[yii 1 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuJWd.png)

but, when i developed yii2 application, it did not work. to be more exact, menu elements of mobile version also appeared.
[yii2 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQvCO.png)
i registred it by using registerJsFile and inserted following code inside AppAsset:

```
public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_BEGIN];
```

How can i fix the error of appearing both mobile and web version menu items in the web version of web application. (remove mobile version menu links from web version).

Answer (score 0):

On my Yii 2 projects I usually use the mobile detect library https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/.
It is easy to implement in your project (e.g. https://github.com/alexandernst/yii2-device-detect/ library). In your code you can add something like next:

```
                ...
                <li class="expanded navigationList-item">
                <a href="#section806" class="navigationList-link">моe цели</a></li>
                <li class="last leaf navigationList-item--border navigationList-item">
                    <a href="https://www.chamber.com/contact" class="navigationList-link">Личины кабинет</a>
                </li>

                <? if(isMobile()) ?>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myMenu()" class="click">&#9776;</a>
                    <ul class="nav" id="nav_bar">
                        <li><a href="#section803">Наши контакты</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section804">О компании</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section805">О членство ТПП</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section806">моe цели</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Личины кабинет</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <? endif;?>
            </ul>
            ...
```